# layout within layout android

Tags: android, layout

[image: Sorry for the really bad free hand paint skills. Thats a sideways phone, split down the middle with 4 buttons and a text box on each side. My posted code only has 4 buttons and a text box because I cant get the layout right for the other set of buttons.]I want to have several layouts inside a layout so that I can better organize the UI. What I want is the layout to be horizontal. I need the layout to be split in half horizontally down the middle and the 4 buttons and text box to be on one side and copied on the other side as well so it can keep track of two totals. I only have one set of buttons right now because I cant get the layouts right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="250.0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@id/button_add"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="+1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/button_add_5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="+5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/currentlife"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minWidth="120.0dip"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="40.0dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@id/button_minus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="-1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/button_minus_5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="-5" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `<include />` tag

Comment: Is it possible that you could draw out what you want to look like in paint or some simple program first (just a very rough idea) so we have a better idea what you are looking for?

Comment: When you say horizontal you mean you want a line cut that devices the top and the bottom?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want it to be like a rectangle(Phone turned sideways) and it is divided into two squares down the middle. Each side would have the 4 buttons and text box

Comment: What is your question???

Comment: how to split the layout into two so that I can have a set of buttons and a text box on one side and the same thing on the other side of the horizontal layout split in half.

Comment: As said Matt Wolfe, without a graphic it will be difficult for anybody to answer you correctly. We need to see what result you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this (fix id's so they aren't duplicate):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/currentlife"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="20"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_add"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="+1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_add_5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="+5" />
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_minus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="+@id/button_minus_5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/currentlife"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:text="20"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_add"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="+1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_add_5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="+5" />
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_minus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="+@id/button_minus_5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your top code worked really well. A small change I would like to make would be for the layouts to go extend all the way down the screen. I would like the 4 buttons to be stacked on top of eachother and not so long, with the text box above them a little more then half way up the screen. I am super new to android, first week of teaching myself so I appologize for the noob questions

Comment: If you  make the layout extend all the way down you will have a lot of white space or huge buttons.

Comment: the white space is fine, I am going to end up putging a picture as the backgound eventually.

Comment: looks great thank you. one last question, how can i make the buttons uniform in size?

Comment: They were the same size on my screen.. I didn't test on an actual device though. Do you mean you want them to fill the space better?

Comment: Also on stack overflow you should Accept answers that solve your problem (not just upvote)

Comment: yeah i want them to all the the same uniform size. it looks like the minus buttons are smaller then the plus buttons. I didnt accept yet because I was off line for the last day but i did it now. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Give weight for two horizontal layouts.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="1.0">
```

Comment: the weight for both should just be 1?

Comment: maybe I did something wrong but by doing that it just has two layouts that are full screen on top of eachother

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this and let me know is it ok for ur requirement ?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+1" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+5" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/currentlife"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-1" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_minus_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create left and right layouts as separate layouts and inflate it in the main layout. This will simplify the layout design.

And try to start the design with **android:layout_width="fill_parent"** instead of **android:layout_width="250.0dip"**

Once you get the layout you want, then try to adjust the width as you need.